# What is the difference between two scopes in the same controller (one from a service) to a directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I've got the below controller with two scope variables and only one passes through to my directive?

```
.controller('newsController', ['$scope', 'gasPrices',
                                  function($scope, gasPrices) { 

  gasPrices.success(function(data) {
    $scope.gasFeed = data.series[0];    
  });

  $scope.myData02 = [2.095,2.079,2.036,1.988,1.882,1.817,1.767,1.747];

}])
;
```

I've got a directive that accepts one scope but not the other?

This works

```
<line-chart chart-data="myData02"></line-chart>
```

This doesn't

```
<line-chart chart-data="gasFeed"></line-chart>
```

Do you know why?

Comment: gasFeed will be available when there is a success callback.  Meantime, myData02 will be loaded with data when the controller loads.

Comment: Thank you Thillai, that makes sense. I will look into how to defer or resolve the success callback delay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to delay instantiating the directive until the data from your async service is available. Something like:

```
<line-chart ng-if="gasFeed" chart-data="gasFeed"></line-chart>
```

This should not instantiate the directive until the gasFeed scope property has data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.controller('newsController', ['$scope', 'gasPrices',
                                  function($scope, gasPrices) { 
  //Create a object that will be pass in the directive, then when this variable
  //it's loaded, the value in the directive (if the scope of the directive uses the '=' binding) will be updated
  $scope.gasFeed = {}; 

  gasPrices.success(function(data) {
    $scope.gasFeed = data.series[0];    
  });

  $scope.myData02 = [2.095,2.079,2.036,1.988,1.882,1.817,1.767,1.747];

}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Here, in your example you can access `gasFeed` scope only when when there is a success callback from the service. Hence, till then `myData02` scope will be loaded.

If you want to access both. Then try this **:**

```
.controller('newsController', ['$scope', 'gasPrices',
                                  function($scope, gasPrices) { 

  gasPrices.success(function(data) {
    $scope.gasFeed = data.series[0];
    $scope.myData02 = [2.095,2.079,2.036,1.988,1.882,1.817,1.767,1.747];    
  });
}]);
```